# I cannot run the project gives the error STG_E_FILENOTFOUND in visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I cannot run the project it gives the error message
`Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030002 (STG_E_FILENOTFOUND)`

But the issue is that the error is shown only for the following project. I can build and run any other project.

I tried rebuilding the project after deleting the `bin` and the `obj` folders from the project but it still didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Firstly, your error information is not complete, and it is impossible to directly judge the problem based on this. Secondly, you don't add project code through `github` or `OneDrive`, so we could not directly solve the problem for you. By searching, you can try to reinstall the corresponding package.

Answer (score 4):

Removing the solution .vs hidden folder and all the bin & obj files worked for me. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to first run the application in debug mode (F5), then run the application without debugging (ctrl + F5).